# Как отобразить вкладку Upload (для картинок) в редакторе ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

Пишу такой код:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'text', {
        filebrowserUploadUrl: "{{route('ckeditor.image-upload', ['_token' => csrf_token() ])}}",
        filebrowserUploadMethod: 'form'
    });
</script>
<textarea class="form-control ckeditor" name="text" placeholder="Текст (html)" required rows="10"></textarea>
```

Почему у редактора по нажатию на пиктограмму "Картинка" в окошке не появляется вкладка "Upload" для загрузки картинок? На конструкцию `{{route('ckeditor.image-upload', ['_token' => csrf_token() ])}}` не обращайте внимания, это на ларавел, мог бы там быть такой же просто php код по обработки загрузки картинки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запустив ваш код у себя, мне сначала выдавало ошибку:

```
[CKEDITOR] Error code: editor-incorrect-element.
{
  "element": "text"
}
[CKEDITOR] For more information about this error go to https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_errors.html#editor-incorrect-element
```

Банально перейдя по ссылке, которую мне библиотека и предложила, выяснил, что проблема в том, что `CKEDITOR` не находит элемент, который как я понимаю он заменяет. (не знаком с библиотекой, не уверен). И это логично.

Второй тег `script` и его содержимое, переношу под `textarea`. И всё. Вкладка "Загрузить" появляется.

В принципе проблема решена. Но немного пройду дальше. Теперь мне в консоль выводится следующая ошибка:

```
[CKEDITOR] Error code: editor-element-conflict.
{
  "editorName": "text"
}
[CKEDITOR] For more information about this error go to https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_errors.html#editor-element-conflict
```

Так же прочитал описание ошибки на сайте, и заметив класс `ckeditor`, я предположил, что `ckeditor` по умолчанию цепляется к элементу у которого есть класс `ckeditor`, по этому при второй попытке `CKEDITOR.replace('text', ...);` выдает ошибку. Так и оказалось, по этому я убрал этот класс.

Вот полный исправленный код:

```html
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" name="text" placeholder="Текст (html)" required rows="10"></textarea>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('text', {
        filebrowserUploadUrl: "{{route('ckeditor.image-upload', ['_token' => csrf_token() ])}}",
        filebrowserUploadMethod: 'form'
    });
</script>
```

P.s. я хотел вставить код выше в сниппет, но почему-то в сниппете выдается постоянно ошибка `Script error`. Что это за ошибка я не выяснил, но код выше просто никак не хочет работать в сниппете. Чтобы я не делал.

Comment: то есть проблема была лишь в порядке скрипта и textarea? У себя поменял, тоже появилась вкладка для изображений. Спасибо! Ставлю голос.

Comment: @IntegralAL получается так) просто решил расписать полный процесс дебаггинга, хотя ответ в вмещается в одно предложение.